# How to use vue-apollo with Nativescript

Tags: nativescript-vue, vue-apollo

I need some help to get apollo-client running with Nativescript VUE:

Here are my files:

*vue-apollo.js*

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from  'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

import store from '../store';

const httpEndpoint = (() => store.getters['application/graphHttp']);

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: httpEndpoint
});

const authMiddleware = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    let token = null;

    await store.dispatch('auth/getToken')
        .then((accessToken) => {
            token = accessToken;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('error getting token from vuex store');
        });

    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
            'X-APP-VERSION': global.APP_VERSION,
            'X-APP-TOKEN': global.VUE_X_APP_TOKEN,
        },
    };
});

const errorMiddleware = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
        if (graphQLErrors[0].message === 'in maintenance') {
            console.error('application in maintenance mode');
        }
    } else if (networkError) {
        console.error('network error detected');
    }
})

const defaultOptions =  {
    link: errorMiddleware.concat(authMiddleware.concat(httpLink)),
    persisting: false,
    websocketsOnly: false,
    ssr: false,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultHttpLink: false,
}

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    ...defaultOptions
});

Vue.use(VueApollo);

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient
});

export default apolloProvider;


export function getApolloClient() {
    return apolloClient;
}

export function createApolloProvider(options = {}) {
    return new VueApollo({
        defaultClient: apolloClient,
    });
}
```

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import App from './App';
import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools'

import store from './store'
import apolloProvider from './vendors/vue-apollo';

// Prints Vue logs when --env.production is *NOT* set while building
Vue.config.silent = (TNS_ENV === 'production')


new Vue({
  store,
  apolloProvider,
  template: `
        <App />
    `,
  components: {
    App
  }
}).$start();
```

*component.vue*

```
<template>
    <Button @tap="toggleLike" text="test" /> 
</template>

<script>
    import TOGGLE_LIKE from '../../../graphql/mutation/toggle-like.graphql';

    export default {
        methods: {
            toggleLike() {
                this.$apollo.mutate({
                    mutation: TOGGLE_LIKE,
                    variables: {
                        postId,
                    },
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    this.waitingForLike = false;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Now when i try to run mutation "toggleLike" the whole application crashes with following error:

> file: node_modules/vue-apollo/dist/vue-apollo.esm.js:1235:29: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.provider.defaultClient')

Where is the error? Can somebody help?